# php convert hex to decimal not working

Tags: php, hex, decimal, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a hexadecimal value of 0d0c140d2f3b to decimal. hexdec() and base_convert() are giving me a value of 14345527177019

the value should be 13 12 20 13 47 59

```
   private function convert_rtc($hex_rtc) {
        $rtc = hexdec($hex_rtc);
        return $rtc;
```

If I should be using a different function let me know. Thank you

Comment: It's giving you the correct value. You apparently want to convert every 2 hex digits into a separate number, rather than converting the whole thing, which is an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split your original value of `0d0c140d2f3b` into blocks of two characters each (e.g. `0d` `0c` `14` `0d` `2f` and `3b`), then use hexdec() on each individual block

PHP's [str_split()](http://www.php.net/function.str-split) function should be useful here

**EDIT**

for example

```
function convert_rtc($hex_rtc) {
    $rtc = array_map(
        'hexdec',
        str_split($hex_rtc, 2)
    );
    return $rtc;
}

$hexString = '0d0c140d2f3b';

$result = convert_rtc($hexString);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this..

<?php
var_dump(hexdec("See"));
var_dump(hexdec("ee"));
// both print "int(238)"

var_dump(hexdec("that")); // print "int(10)"
var_dump(hexdec("a0")); // print "int(160)"
?>
```